# proof of an Integer division of a and b with negative a and positive b

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm solving the following question in my professor's textbook:

Consider $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $a<0$ and $b>0$.

Let $q,\, r,\, q',\, r'\, \in \Bbb{Z}\,$ such that:
$$ -a = bq' + r'\quad \text{and} \quad 0 \leq r' < b $$
and
$$ a = bq + r\quad \text{and} \quad 0 \leq r < b $$

We intend to prove that if:

1. If $r' = 0$ then $ q = - q'$ and $r = 0$ (Trivial, substituting and applying uniqueness of q and r);
2. If $r' \neq 0$ then $ q = - (q' + 1)$ and $r = b - r'$.

I have already solved 1, but am stuck at an impasse at 2... We know $0 < r' < b$, and we can easily $r = b - r'$ by derivating $bq + r = -bq' - r'$. However, I have not been able to see how to prove the $q$ component.

Any ideas on how to prove this parcel?

(I don't need any detailed proofs, a starting point/layout would suffice, I still intend to solve it on my own, after all)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I changed your notation to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: Add the two equations and use that $r'\neq 0$ implies $0 < r+r' < 2b$.  You get $0 = (q'+q + 1)b$, so...

Comment: (What is the time limit, for multiple edits in a short time being combined into one edit? I thought it was 5 minutes, but evidently it's less.)

Comment: (Ah, comments prevent edits being combined: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20045/is-the-5-minute-grace-period-suddenly-gone-or-is-it-just-me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any reference to whether $r'$ is $0$ or not, we can add the two equations
$$a = bq' + r' \\ -a = bq + r$$
to find
$$0 = b(q'+q) + (r'+r),$$
and therefore
$$q'+q = -\frac{r'+r}b.$$

Further, by adding the inequalities $0 \leq r < b$ and $0 \leq r' < b$,
$$0 \leq r'+r < 2b \\ 0 \leq \frac{r'+r}b < 2 \\ -2 < q'+q \leq 0.$$

Since $q', q$ are integers, this shows $q'+q = 0$ or $q'+q = -1$.

The rest is casework:

> Case 1. $q'+q = 0$:  Then $0 = b(0) + r'+r$ which by $r,r' \geq 0$ implies $r=r'=0$.

> Case 2. $q'+q = -1$:  Then $0 + b(-1) + r' + r$, so $r = b-r'$, which by $r,r' < b$ implies $r,r' > 0$.